# How to build HDF5 library for armv7 in order to use with iOS?

Tags: ios, compilation, x86-64, hdf5, armv7

I'm stuck with my iOS app (Objective-C).

I'm building an application for my iOS device and I need to use the [HDF5 library](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/).

However during my compilation I have some errors :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_H5T_NATIVE_FLOAT_g", referenced from:
      int flann::(anonymous namespace)::get_hdf5_type<float>() in VisualSearchEngine.o
  "_H5open", referenced from:
      int flann::(anonymous namespace)::get_hdf5_type<float>() in VisualSearchEngine.o
  "_H5Dcreate2", referenced from:
      void flann::save_to_file<float>(flann::Matrix<float> const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in VisualSearchEngine.o
  "_H5Fopen", referenced from:
      void flann::save_to_file<float>(flann::Matrix<float> const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in VisualSearchEngine.o
  "_H5Fcreate", referenced from:
      void flann::save_to_file<float>(flann::Matrix<float> const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I did not put all the error for better reading but you got it.

I understand that HDF5 has been built only with one architecture : **x86_64**

Indeed after using the following command line on one of the lib,

```
lipo -info /usr/local/Cellar/hdf5/1.8.17/lib/libhdf5_cpp.dylib
```

I got this message :

```
Non-fat file: /usr/local/Cellar/hdf5/1.8.17/lib/libhdf5_cpp.dylib is architecture: x86_64
```

On my app I use others frameworks and they all are fat file which contains at least the architectures armv7 armv7s i386 and arm64 which is not the case for HDF5.
So It was not a problem.

My question is the following : **How can I build/compile HDF5 with the armv7 architecture ?** Or is there maybe a framework available which contains the corresponding architectures ?

I need to use with the armv7 architecture because I use another framework which contains only the armv7 architecture.

I'm stuck and I don't know how to move forward.

Thank for your help.